# RML ReportaLab left and right padding in a table

Tags: pdf, report, odoo, openerp-7, rml

I am working on a report in openerp v7 and I need to get rid of left and right padding on a table:

[image]

Here's the definition of the blockTable:

```
<blockTableStyle id="Detalle">
      <blockAlignment value="LEFT"/>
      <blockValign value="TOP"/>
    <!--      <lineStyle kind="LINEABOVE" colorName="#000000" thickness="1.0" start="0,0" stop="-1,-1" />
      <lineStyle kind="LINEBELOW" colorName="#000000" thickness="1.0" start="0,0" stop="-1,-1" />   -->
 <lineStyle kind="LINEBEFORE" colorName="#000000" thickness="1.0" start="0,0" stop="-1,-1" />
      <lineStyle kind="LINEAFTER" colorName="#000000" thickness="1.0" start="0,0" stop="-1,-1" />
    </blockTableStyle>
```

And here's the paragraph:

```
<paraStyle name="DetalleRight" fontName="Courier" fontSize="5.5"  leading="3" alignment="RIGHT"/>
```

Thaks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it! the trick was:

```
<blockTableStyle id="Detalle">
  <blockAlignment value="LEFT"/>
  <blockValign value="TOP"/>
  <blockLeftPadding length="0.5mm"/>
  <blockRightPadding length="0.5mm"/>
</blockTableStyle>
```

**blockRightPadding** property

Answer (score 0):

**rightIndent="0.5mm"
leftIndent="0.5mm"**

This will work for parastyle tag.